# How is the policy of Theresa May different to that of Jeremy Corbyn in relation to security and terrorism?

Tags: united-kingdom, terrorism

How is the policy of Theresa May different to that of Jeremy Corbyn in relation to security and terrorism?

Good answers should refer to both manifestos, be specific to the general election of 2017 and may make reference to historical attitudes of both leaders towards security and terrorism related topics.

Answer (score 2):

*Excerpts from the respective manifestos are in block quotes.*

### [Labour Party Manifesto 2017](http://www.labour.org.uk/index.php/manifesto2017)

To sum up, the Labour Party hopes to fight terrorism using diplomatic resolutions as well as taking preventative measures at home. They also aim to prevent vulnerable people from being drawn into terrorism and not to alienate any minority communities in UK.

Related article: [Express — Labour manifesto on terrorism: What is Jeremy Corbyn's policy to tackle terror?](http://www.express.co.uk/news/politics/809603/Jeremy-Corbyn-terror-policy-Labour-plan-terrorism-ISIS-Manchster-election-2017)

> **Security and counter-terrorism**
>
> Labour will maintain the cross-border security co-operation agreements with our intelligence partners in Europe and beyond. We will always provide our security agencies with the resources and the powers they need to protect our country and keep us all safe. We will also ensure that such powers do not weaken our individual rights or civil liberties.
>
> When – as they sometimes will – these aims collide, the exercise of investigatory powers must always be both proportionate and necessary. We will reintroduce effective judicial oversight over how and when they are used, when the circumstances demand that our collective security outweighs an individual freedom.
>
> Labour will review the Prevent programme with a view to assessing both its effectiveness and its potential to alienate minority communities. In doing so, we will address the government’s failure to take any effective new measures against a growing problem of extreme or violent radicalisation.

---

> **BORDER SECURITY**
>
> Border security is vital in preventing serious crimes including child abduction, people trafficking, smuggling of drugs and guns, terrorism and modern day slavery.
>
> Contrary to the Conservative government’s rhetoric, they have
>   not taken control of our borders or strengthened our national security. Instead, they have suppressed the independent inspector’s reports highlighting weaknesses in our borders and cut the Border Force
>   by thousands of personnel. They want to turn private sector landlords,
>   teachers, medical staff and other public sector workers into unpaid immigration officers, forcing them to provide information
>   to the authorities.
>
> The Conservatives promised and failed to deliver 100 per cent exit checks at the borders. Labour will recruit 500 more border guards to add to our safeguards and controls.

---

### [Conservative Party Manifesto 2017](https://www.conservatives.com/manifesto)

To sum up, the Conservative Party aims to strengthen cooperation with allies around the world and also to sustain a fine armed force and strengthen the UK's security services. They also aim to set up a new commission to identify and expose examples of extremism and to counter their messages.

Related article: [The Guardian — Theresa May plans anti-extremism drive if Tories win election](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2017/may/25/theresa-may-anti-extremism-drive-tories-manchester-attack)

> **Theresa May’s Conservatives will deliver**
>
> [ ... ]
>
> Security from crime and terrorism, backed by a new national infrastructure police force, a stronger response to white collar crime and our world-leading counter-terrorism strategy.

---

> **Defeating extremism**
>
> Our enjoyment of Britain’s diversity must not prevent us from confronting the menace of extremism. Extremism, especially Islamist extremism, strips some British people, especially women, of the freedoms they should enjoy, undermines the cohesion of our society and can fuel violence. To defeat extremism, we need to learn from how civil society and the state took on racism in the twentieth century. We will consider what new criminal offences might need to be created, and what new aggravated offences might need to be established, to defeat the extremists. We will support the public sector and civil society in identifying extremists, countering their messages and promoting pluralistic, British values. And we will establish a Commission for Countering Extremism to identify examples of extremism and expose them, to support the public sector and civil society, and help the government to identify policies to defeat extremism and promote pluralistic values.

---

> **Our world is full of opportunity but is also driven by conflict, terrorism and threat.**
>
> As a global power, we have a responsibility to sustain our fine armed forces so that they can defend the realm, our overseas territories and our interests around the globe. We will play a leading role in NATO and maintain the ability to conduct strike operations, peacekeeping, security missions and the deployment of a joint expeditionary force. We will maintain the overall size of the armed forces, including an army that is capable of fielding a war- ghting division. We shall expand our reach around the world. We will retain the Trident continuous-at-sea nuclear deterrent to provide the ultimate guarantee of our security.
>
> We have the biggest defence budget in Europe and the second largest in NATO. We will continue to meet the NATO commitment to spend at least 2 per cent of GDP on defence and we will increase the defence budget by at least 0.5 per cent above in ation in every year of the new parliament.

---

> We will continue to invest in our world-leading security services and maintain and develop our counter- terrorism strategy to protect us from terrorism at home and abroad.